# 80Mb mp3 files+40 MB images,what is the best place?assets or Raw?eclipse takes time to Build?(android 3.0)

Tags: android, eclipse, assets

I have approximately 80MB+ mp3 files,40MB images in my project.when I try to put 3MB of each  these files eclipse takes a lot time to build.is it possible to put all these files in Raw or assets folder?what is the solution to make eclipse build fast.

Answer (score 4):

I think for best practice is to make the user download these files after he installes your app since Android market limits your app size to 50MB.

You can use
[AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to download the data asynchronously

Comment: Ok,if we limit the project to below 50MB,what is the best place to put the data,assets or Raw?when I put them in assets or Raw the project did not build immediately and some times throws memory errors and unable to run the project.

Comment: It will depend on what you are using them for. I would go for raw. APK file is like a zip file. It will always take time to package (or zip) 80MB of audio. Also, you should keep in mind that phone memory is not as big as desktop's.

Comment: Ok,is it fine to put all 50MB data in raw folder?

Comment: As I said earlier it is bad design. However, raw folder is designed to hold this kind of data.

Comment: Ok,I have hundreds of mp3s all are upto 80MB,my problem is that application should also work when the user offline.I hope raw folder can store the files up to 50MB,I will think for alternative for remaining 30MB.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue, and came to the same conclusion as khr2003.  I just want to add that the real limit for Android Market is more like 30MB since an app larger than that is impossible to download to most phones -- you will get out of storage errors.